# HTTP POST request not working over 3G

Tags: iphone, http, post, nsurlrequest

When making the following HTTP POST request:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  NSURLResponse     *urlResponse = nil; 
  NSError    *error = nil; 

  // execute
  NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error]; 
  if(responseData)
  {
        //blah
  }
```

I get back a valid response when connected via WiFi, but not when connected over 3G. The responseData object doesn't even get made (0x0) when coming back over 3G.

I get kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.

The response ought to be 242k of JSON.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the server have any firewall rules or access control lists based on IP address? - you'll be coming from a different IP address range on 3G vs. WiFi

Comment: The error means there are problems parsing the headers from the server. That could also mean, that there is an encoding problem.

Comment: Thanks guys.
David - no firewall rules etc. I should have mentioned that I have other requests that work over 3G. The only difference seems to be size I think.
jmz - but why does it work over wifi and not 3G?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that the problem was between the back end system and the mobile networks. Changing the header information to text format only solved the issue.